# Angular 6 template driven form- disabling submit button on edit form

Tags: html, angular, forms, validation

I am creating some template driven forms in an Angular component. The goal is to obviously not let a user submit the form until all the fields are valid. This works well when I am having the user send a POST request, i.e. creating something from scratch.

However, when I have a form to update something, it allows the user to submit the form before when it might not be valid yet. Is this because when I pre-populate the form, the state is altered? What do I need to change to make sure that button stays disabled until it is completely valid?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" #editMPForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="editMonitoringPoint()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left_td">
                                    <p>Monitoring Point Name *</p>
                                    <input type="text" id="name" required #name="ngModel" [class.is-invalid]="name.invalid && name.touched" 
                                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': editMPForm.submitted && name.invalid }" name="name" [(ngModel)]="updated_mp.name" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g., A123 Outfall NW"/>
                                    <small class="text-danger" [class.d-none]="name.valid  || !editMPForm.submitted">Name is required</small>
                                </td>
                                <td class="left_td">
                                    <p>Timezone *</p><i class='fa fa-info-circle op-icon' matTooltip="Timezone in which the Monitoring Point is Located"></i>
                                    <select class="col-md-12 form-control" [(ngModel)]="updated_mp.timezone" name="timezone" #timezone="ngModel" id="timezone" required [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': editMPForm.submitted && timezone.invalid }">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose...</option>
                                        <option value="America/Puerto_Rico">Puerto Rico (Atlantic)</option>
                                        <option value="America/New_York">Eastern Time (US & Canada)</option>
                                        <option value="America/Chicago">Central Time (US & Canada)</option>
                                        <option value="America/Denver">Mountain Time (US & Canada)</option>
                                        <option value="America/Phoenix">Arizona</option>
                                        <option value="America/Los_Angeles">Pacific Time (US & Canada)</option>
                                        <option value="America/Anchorage">Alaska</option>
                                        <option value="Pacific/Honolulu">Hawaii Standard Time</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <small class="text-danger" [class.d-none]="timezone.valid  || !editMPForm.submitted">Timezone is required
                                    </small>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                         </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <button type="submit">Save Edits</button>
                </div>
</form>
```

Part of the issue is that the model requirements have changed since the items were first created. For example, an item that was created when it didn't require a timezone to be added, it now requires you to add a timezone when you use the edit form. I don't want my form to let you submit without adding that required timezone.

Let me know if I can provide any more info! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can set the disabled attribute for the button like so:

```html
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!editMPForm.form.valid">Save Edits</button>
```